# Change data in vertical table to individual rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-concatenation, worksheet-function, unpivot

I have an Excel workbook with the following format:

```
 | A  | B     | C     | D     | E     |   
 |----|-------|-------|-------|-------|  
1|    | po#1  | po#2  | po#3  | po#1  |
2|    | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4 |
3|sku1| qty1  | qty4  | qty7  | qty10 | 
4|sku2| qty2  | qty5  | qty8  | qty11 |
5|sku3| qty3  | qty6  | qty9  | qty12 |
```

that I need to convert to the following format:

```
  | A      | B     | C     | D     |
  |--------|-------|-------|-------|
 1|  po#1  | date1 | sku1  | qty1  |
 2|  po#1  | date1 | sku2  | qty2  |
 3|  po#1  | date1 | sku3  | qty3  |
 4|  po#1  | date4 | sku1  | qty10 |
 5|  po#1  | date4 | sku2  | qty11 |
 6|  po#1  | date4 | sku3  | qty12 |
 7|  po#2  | date2 | sku1  | qty4  |
 8|  po#2  | date2 | sku2  | qty5  |
 9|  po#2  | date2 | sku3  | qty6  |
10|  po#3  | date3 | sku1  | qty7  |
11|  po#3  | date3 | sku2  | qty8  |
12|  po#3  | date3 | sku3  | qty9  |
```

without using VBA.

Comment: create a temporary column and transpose the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a copy, delete Row2 and apply the reverse pivot technique detailed (with pictures!) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal/20543651#20543651). When you get to the Table, switch the order of the `Row` and `Column` columns and insert a new column between the two. Populate this with an HLOOKUP from your original data (that still has Row2). Sort ascending on Column `Value`. Delete the labels and, if desired, convert Table to Range.

*Edit* Above addresses an earlier version of the OP. To address the current version Rows1 and 2 could be replaced with the result of a formula such as `=A1&"|"&A2` (based on the contents of A1 and A2 *before* replacement) with copying across to suit, then splitting these apart again in the Table by text manipulation with searching for `|`.

Comment: Very helpful - but we're missing a step. Sometimes there is the same "po#" with different "date" values, so doing the HLOOKUP will not necessarily matchup the "date" with the correct "po#".

Comment: Yes I should have been clearer from the start. Thanks for trying to help anyway pnuts! I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: Thanks pnuts! That did it.

Comment: This was very helpful - I want to see how to do it with VBA. I've posted a separate question with the same problem but asking for a solution with VBA. Pnuts if you know how to do it would be very helpful!    Question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532185/change-data-in-vertical-table-to-individual-rows-using-vba