# Change data in vertical table to individual rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with the following format:

```
  | A  | B     | C     | D     | E     |   
  |----|-------|-------|-------|-------|  
 1|    | po#1  | po#2  | po#3  | po#1  |
 2|    | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4 |
 3|sku1| qty1  | qty4  | qty7  | qty10 | 
 4|sku2| qty2  | qty5  | qty8  | qty11 |
 5|sku3| qty3  | qty6  | qty9  | qty12 |
```

that I need to convert to the following format:

```
  | A      | B     | C     | D     |
  |--------|-------|-------|-------|
 1|  po#1  | date1 | sku1  | qty1  |
 2|  po#1  | date1 | sku2  | qty2  |
 3|  po#1  | date1 | sku3  | qty3  |
 4|  po#1  | date4 | sku1  | qty10 |
 5|  po#1  | date4 | sku2  | qty11 |
 6|  po#1  | date4 | sku3  | qty12 |
 7|  po#2  | date2 | sku1  | qty4  |
 8|  po#2  | date2 | sku2  | qty5  |
 9|  po#2  | date2 | sku3  | qty6  |
10|  po#3  | date3 | sku1  | qty7  |
11|  po#3  | date3 | sku2  | qty8  |
12|  po#3  | date3 | sku3  | qty9  |
```

using VBA.

Comment: I don't quite see your question here. Remember that SO is not a code writing service but rather a forum to get assistance on specific issues with programming. Try coming up with a solution and if you run into specific issues with your code then you can post it here for assistance. One way to start is to use the Macro Recorder and move a couple of cells to what you want it. Then reviewing your code you can adapt it to scale to the rest of your sheet. Hope this guides you on your way. Cheers.

Comment: Hi nbayly, mea culpa, I am trying to use this as a code writing service because I had no idea where to start. I have no knowledge of VBA and am trying to learn by solving some of the problems I'm facing every day.

Answer (score 1):

If your headers are all contained in rows 1:2 and column A:A, then you could use this code:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range
Dim rowWrite As Long

rowWrite = 1
Set sht1 = ActiveSheet
Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
For Each cel In sht1.Range("B3", sht1.Range("B2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown).Address)
    With sht2.Range("A" & rowWrite)
        .Offset(, 0).Value = cel.EntireColumn.Resize(1).Value
        .Offset(, 1).Value = cel.EntireColumn.Resize(1).Offset(1).Value
        .Offset(, 2).Value = cel.EntireRow.Resize(1).Value
        .Offset(, 3).Value = cel.Value
    End With
    rowWrite = rowWrite + 1
Next cel
```

This will create a new worksheet and write your data to that.
It won't preserve formatting, let me know if you need that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Andrew, this is great, thank you! How would you preserve formatting?