# How can I fill an Excel array without using VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel

I have data in the format (Observed value, Number of observations) and would like to convert it to an array of values.  For example, if I had (Value = 12, Number of observations = 3), I would like to use built-in formulas to create 3 cells each containing the number 12.  Is this possible? [This is an example of what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzVGJ.png) Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA then you'll have to do it manually. The only thing which might facilitate your manual work (which I can currently think of) would be to `UNPIVOT` the table. There are plenty of examples and solutions on the web [including StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unpivot%20excel?mode=all). The following solution might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507842/change-data-in-vertical-table-to-individual-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to accept **empty string** instead of **blank** then, assuming your first column of inputs are in **A1:A2**, fill your output range for column A starting from A4 with:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW(A$4)<A$2,A$1,"")
```

You can avoid the reference to the top cell by using:

```
=IF(ROW()-MIN(ROW())<A$2,A$1,"")
```

Make it an array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in the output range of column A.

You can copy either of these to the right to support additional columns.

Comment: Why an array formula? This modified formula from your `=IF(ROW()-ROW($F$1)<A$2,A$1,"")` works fine. `A$2` is the #Observed for Value in `A$1`. `$F$1` is the first cell where the output is required. Drag this formula in both direction as required

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've edited my answer to reflect what you've used, and my original intention which removes the need to reference the first cell of the output range.